# Mouse movement via SendInput results in logoff

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, sendinput

**SOLUTION** (thanks Adrian Mole! I never would have guessed):

> You must set the `.time` member of the `MOUSEINPUT` part of the union (to zero).

============

Original **Question**:

I am trying to move the mouse using frequent SendInput calls:

```
void MoveMouse(int dX, int dY)
{
    INPUT Input;
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dx = dX;
    Input.mi.dx = dY;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    Input.mi.time = 0;   //  <--  THIS SOLVES IT
    Input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 1234;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
}
```

This does work pretty much as intented, however, after a short while, the user is logged off and presented with the Windows login screen.
Does anyone know how / why this could be happening, and how I could prevent this?

My google search came up blank. I tried to delay the calls with different approaches, assuming that too many SendInput's might send Windows into panic, but it still occurs seemingly at random.

Comment: `dwExtraInfo = 1234` - Why that? Message extra info is rarely used. Well, except for mouse messages, where [it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages). Might want to share a [mcve]. The little we can see raises enough concerns to warrant that.

Comment: I am using dwExtraInfo to identify the movement that I am sending, so that when my application receives messages from it, they just pass it through. The purpose of my application is to fix the mouse for another application that does not work properly with RDP. So I am using a low level mouse hook to intercept and block WM_MOUSEMOVE, meanwhile my application catches WM_INPUT, translates it into the appropriate relative movement, and sends it out again with SendInput.

Comment: If you are using a low-level mouse hook already, you can ignore injected input right there. The information is recorded in the `flags` field of the [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) structure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, the application that i am trying to tame, poorly injects movement itself via SetCursorPos, which I am trying to surpress.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you couldn't be suppressing injected input from your low-level mouse hook, without hijacking the message extra data that is being used.

Comment: Because when my application injects movement, I want my low-level mouse hook to return `CallNextHookEx`, but when any other application injects movement, I want the hook to `return 1`. Do you think `Input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 1234` might cause the logoff?

Comment: The extra message information for mouse messages is data that *is* being used by programs, so you can safely expect that any value (other than 0) will have any number of effects. What is and why it is happening is something you'll have to investigate. The event log is a place to go looking for answers, and then a debugger once you've narrowed down the number of potential candidates.

Comment: @GusAnders `SetCursorPos()` doesn't inject mouse movement into the input queue. A low-level mouse hook can detect true injected input, such as from `SendInput()`, by looking for the `LLMHF_INJECTED` and `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flags in the `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` struct

Comment: You **must** set the `.time` member of the `MOUSEINPUT` part of the union (to zero). See linked duplicate.